# Toolbar transparente no Android

Tags: java, android

Preciso fazer com que minha `toolbar` fique transparente, ou pelo menos remover aquela linha sombreada que fica abaixo dela. Alguém já passou por uma situação parecida?

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SOPT, antes faça um tour http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e caso já tenha tentado algo coloque para podemos ajudar melhor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Elevação

Aquela "linha sombreada" que lhe diz respeito se trata do `elevation`. Você pode remover setando o valor dela para `0dp`. Então seu código ficaria assim:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       android:elevation="0dp"
       android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
       app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
       app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

## Toolbar Transparente

Referente a transparência, uma das formas de você fazer isso é você trabalhar com seu `style`. Tudo que você precisa é definir o tema que esconde o `toolbar`, definindo o estilo da barra de ação com fundo transparente e definir este estilo para o `widget` da barra de ferramentas.

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

#### Layout Transparente

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Toolbar should be above content-->
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Toolbar Layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"/>
```

**Outra forma seria assim:**

Você pode definir o plano de fundo para Android, do padrão de cor transparente, o que funciona muito bem. Adicione isso ao layout que deseja uma barra de ferramentas transparente:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Se você quer mudar o alfa programaticamente, você pode modificar o alfa no próprio fundo da barra de ferramentas. Basta obter uma instância da `drawable` e definir o `alpha`:

```
mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
mToolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou testar aqui agora mesmo.